# Facing issue in serialization using jackson in spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

When I try to return `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>` from the RestController, I get the following error:

> "message": "Could not write JSON: Class java.util.ArrayList not subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class java.util.ArrayList not subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]

Can some help me with the solution?

Comment: We need more clues. Can you please show your code?

Comment: Could you show how this rest method looks like and what annotation do you use?